# The server "serverName" did not accept the certificate

Tags: ipad, osx-server, server.app, mobile-device-management, profile-manager

I'm trying to install a profile that I've created on an iPad. I have the Trust Profile for the device installed and verified.

The problem arises when trying to enrol the iPad.

Below is the output from the iPhone Configuration Utility console.

Any suggestions on what I can do to solve this?

```
    Desc   : Profile Installation Failed
    Sugg   : Profile Failed to Install
    US Desc: Profile Installation Failed
    US Sugg: Profile Failed to Install
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : Profile Failed to Install
    Sugg   : The profile “Remote Management” could not be installed.
    US Desc: Profile Failed to Install
    US Sugg: The profile “Remote Management” could not be installed.
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The profile “Remote Management” could not be installed.
    Sugg   : The payload “Device Management” could not be installed.
    US Desc: The profile “Remote Management” could not be installed.
    US Sugg: The payload “Device Management” could not be installed.
    Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
    Code   : 1009
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "Remote Management"
    )
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The payload “Device Management” could not be installed.
    Sugg   : The server “serverName” did not accept the certificate.
    US Desc: The payload “Device Management” could not be installed.
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "Device Management"
    )
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The server “serverName” did not accept the certificate.
    Domain : NSURLErrorDomain
    Code   : -1205
    Type   : MCFatalError
```

Comment: How did you create the profile on the iPad?

Comment: Using OS X Servers Profile Manager.

Comment: The answer can be found in the post below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177478/unable-to-install-ios-mdm-configuration-profile